# How do I calculate the frequency of a sound using python

Tags: python, audio, fft, audio-processing

I have a .wav file, and I need to write code that tells me the frequency in hz of the sound. How do I go about this? I've done some research and all of them point me to something thats related to fft, numpy, matplotlib and so on. I don't need to plot the sound, I just need to calculate the frequency of the sound as it plays on. How do I go about this? Any help or advice that will help me start is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use a library. The WAVE in the standard library has getframerate() Returns sampling frequency. PyWave seems to be useful as well.

Comment: thanks for the comment, can you please explain to me what the difference is between the actual frequency of a sound and sampling frequency?

Comment: in the real world audio naturally is continuous meaning the audio wave or more directly the motion of that wobbling guitar string or your ear drum wobbles continuously however to get audio into a computer that continuous audio wave needs to get measured which happens X times per second which is the sampling frequency this measures the audio curve height at that point in time .. CD quality audio gets sampled 44100 times per second ... the other fundamental attribute is bit depth which is the number of bits of storage allocated to store each of those audio samples .. typically 2 bytes per sample

Comment: thanks for the comment scott, but i don't want the sampling frequency of the sound. I want to calculate the actual frequency of the sound. Is this where we use fft?

Comment: Sampling frequency is the number of times per second that you ask about the current value of the wave. The value at any moment in time is the frequency. One is how many times you measure it. The other is the measurement itself. Google it a bit. Professionals know much more than me.

Comment: @TupacShakur "the frequency of a sound".  Is there just a sinusoid in the wave file? Or is it music?

Comment: @Quant1892387 i am trying to calculate the frequency of the sound itself, that is the measurement itself.

Comment: @pierpy it is a musical note played from the guitar

Comment: Ok, a library does the job. Or, implement a FFT yourself, but it can take whole life for a beginner…

Comment: This article could help: https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft. There's a code sample for fft also. A sound normally contains multiple audio waves with different frequencies, that change over time, it's not just a number in Hz for an input audio file. The simplest case is a sine wave, it would have the same frequency over time, say 440 Hz, which is the classical wave to start with when learning the audio processing. So I'd recommend to first understand the basic audio processing theory, what is FFT, the difference between time and frequency domains.

Comment: And you can basically search "python audio fft" for example (in the internet or even stackoverflow) and check some examples of how to get FFT from an audio file, plot it to visually see which frequencies are found in the audio and get the actual data if you don't need the graphic data.